# Plotting a simple graph with more than 1 variables

Tags: plotting

Here's what I did:

```
Plot[(Q E^(-(x^2/(4 t))))/(2 Sqrt[π t]), {x, 0, 10}]
```

I want only x to vary. But Mathematica is giving me a blank plot. It's very strange.

---

I have tried stipulating the domain for the other 2 variables but Mathematica says

> "Limiting value {Q,0,100} in {{x,0,100},{Q,0,100},{t,0,100}} is not a machine-sized real number""

Comment: Because you did not assign numerical values to `Q` and `t`, the blank plot is *Mathematica*'s way of saying it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Then you will want to look at `ContourPlot3D[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should assign values ​​and improve the typos. Howsoever I think you are looking for:

```
Q = 1/2;
t = 9;
Plot[(Q E^(-(x^2/(4 t))))/(2 Sqrt[π t])
 , {x, 0, 10}
 , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

A Family of Functions can be plottet the following way:

```
f[x_, t_, Q_] := (Q E^(-(x^2/(4 t))))/(2 Sqrt[π t])
tabl = Table[f[x, t, Q], {t, Range[6, 10]}, {Q, Range[1, 5]}]
Plot[Evaluate@tabl
, {x, 0, 10}
, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: The iterator for `Q` has an unnecessary set of list brackets which results in only 5 plots rather than 25. Change the iterator to `{Q, Range[1, 5]}` to see all 25.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, done so, very attentive, I thank You.

Comment: As you undoubtedly noticed, not all of the `PlotLegends` are displayed. With this many curves you might find `Tooltip` more useful. `tabl = Table[Tooltip[f[x, t, Q], {t, Q, f[x, t, Q]}], {t, Range[6, 10]}, {Q, Range[1, 5]}] // Flatten;`

Answer (score 0):

Since `Q` is just a multiplicative constant, perhaps you're after one of these:

```
Q = 1/2;

f[x_, t_] := Q /2 Exp[-x^2/(4 t)]/Sqrt[π t]; 

Grid[{{
  Plot3D[f[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), 
          PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.7], Orange, Specularity[Red, 100]}],

   ContourPlot[f[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}, 
                ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ContourLabels -> True],

   DensityPlot[f[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 5}, 
               ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]